# mingw g++ Windows Subsystem WinMain not getting hInstance value

Tags: winforms, mingw, directx, entry-point, hinstance

I'm converting a VS2015 C++ directx/winforms app to VS code using mingw G++ (both on windows 10).

I have it compiling and linking after adding the -mwindows option (and a whole bunch of libraries) but upon stepping into the WinMain there is no value in hInstance.

```
#include <objbase.h>
#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE,g_szAppName, MAX_LOADSTRING);
...
```

Which results in anything depending on it like LoadString or RegisterClassEx not working.

What should I be looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure what *"no value in hInstance"* is supposed to mean but you can always get executable handle by calling `GetModuleHandle` with `NULL`.

Comment: The value of hInstance in the g++ version when compared to vs2015 version

Comment: Disregard.  It wasn't the problem. But what I meant was. The value of hInstance in the g++ version was a suspicious and same round number 0x040000 compared to vs2015 version which was random and different number on each invocation.  However this turned out to be the difference between a g++ 32 bit and vs 64 bit.  I compared the hInstance value to another working example I downloaded and it too got the same hinstance value and has no trouble creating windows. The actual problem will be in another thread.

Comment: The actual problem turned out to be compiling the rc file with windres.